# Is improvement on following Fortran code possible?

Tags: optimization, fortran

Here’s one of the completed programs using that particular algorithm.

```
        program Lotto

        implicit none

        INTEGER::MAXTHREADS
        INTEGER::I,N,Q,RAN,RAN4(4),N129(9),LOTTO5(5)
        REAL::R,TI,TIMELY,SEC

        CALL RANDOM_SEED()
!____________________________________________________________________________
!____________________________________________________________________________

        N=0
        RAN4=0
        DO
            CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(R)
            RAN=1+INT(9*R)
            IF(COUNT(RAN==RAN4(1:4))/=0)CYCLE
            N=N+1
            RAN4(N)=RAN
            IF(N==4)EXIT
        ENDDO

        N129=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
        N129(RAN4(1:4))=0

        N=0
        DO I=1,9
            IF(N129(I)==0)CYCLE
            N=N+1
            LOTTO5(N)=I
        ENDDO    
        PRINT*,LOTTO5

        end program Lotto
```

In response to my original post, High Performance Mark made two important observations:

1. There is little that can be said about a snippet of code without seeing the context in which it is used; and
2. It is probably not worth the time to bother with anything that minor anyway. (Apologies for paraphrasing.)

The above short program, “Lotto”, is intended only as a minor demo to show – in context – how the filter algorithm can be used. Certainly as a collection of only a few lines of code, it may not be improvable. However, I had hoped otherwise. When dealing with 1500 to 2000 lines of new Fortran code each day, and similar code snippets appear 10 or 12 times within the same program, if you can improve (optimize) one, you can optimize them all for at least some reduction in execution time, which speaks indirectly to HPM’s 2nd observation. As a Fortran programmer, I have only one goal, and that is to produce the desired results with the shortest possible execution time. That’s the nice way to say it. The more realistic statement is: “To produce the desired results, spending the least amount of money.” Since “optimization” is one of the many tags that Stack Overflow uses, I was in hopes some discussions involving optimization might be pursued, but apparently that is not the case. Some other forum, I presume. Some younger users might be interested in how code optimization works, but many of them seem pretty much preoccupied with their most immediate failure to get certain code collections to execute correctly.

HPM’s criticisms are always spot on when he reviews a post, so here are my final two apologies to him:

1. You are right about removing statements. There were 15 operational Fortran statements, 3 comment lines, & 2 OMP directives making up the “preparatory” section of the program. From that total of 20 I should have omitted 14 of them, including the 3 comment lines & the 2 OMP directives, for clarity. I have now removed them. However, my Microsoft Visual Studio is set up to execute all programs using OMP, and it also executes “Lotto” just the way it is, giving thread count and other thread info. Lotto runs fine in OMP, but for demo purposes I certainly did not need all of that ‘lettuce’.
2. I’m sorry about the multi-statement lines. I do not use that in my ordinary programming. It was there because I had been of the opinion that Stock Overflow wanted programs that they print to be as short and concise as possible. Was I wrong about that? I have removed multi-lining.

Comment: Your code looks reasonably efficient and is not too hard to understand. That makes it good code in my eyes. Then again, you might want to look into masks and the `where` statements to see whether you can eliminate the `BOX` array from your code in the first place.

Comment: Note this is a real wall of text ( http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_Text ). I would have adjusted it for better readability but I don§t even know where to begin. It is good to make concise and structured posts. edit:I tried at least something.

Comment: Re your last point: Programs here should be concise but not over-compressed at the expense of readability. They should be concise to be quickly and easily understood. When you compress everything it is hard to read and hard to be understood.

Comment: Please do not vandalise your posts. Once you have submitted a post, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large ([under the CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 5):

OK, I've taken the bait ...

If I understand the code correctly (and if I don't then you can ignore this entire answer) it selects (in the example) a random 5 elements (no element twice) of the array `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`.

After a little head scratching I've cast this problem as one of making a random permutation of the array and selecting the first 5 elements.  Here's a little function wot I wrote to make a random permutation using Knuth's shuffle

```
  FUNCTION random_perm(n) RESULT(perm)
    ! return a random permutation of the integers 1..n, uses Knuth's shuffle
    INTEGER, INTENT(in) :: n
    INTEGER, DIMENSION(n) :: perm
    INTEGER, DIMENSION(n) :: randi
    REAL, DIMENSION(n) :: randr
    INTEGER :: tmp, ix, jx

    CALL random_SEED()
    CALL random_NUMBER(randr)
    randi = 1+INT(n*randr)
    perm = [(ix,ix=1,n)]

    DO ix = 1, n-1
       jx = randi(ix)
       tmp = perm(ix)
       perm(ix) = perm(jx)
       perm(jx) = tmp
    END DO  

  END FUNCTION random_perm
```

OP could use the function like this:

```
n129 = random_perm(9)
lotto5 = n129(1:5)
```

At this point `lotto5` isn't sorted.  If that's important one way to 'sort' the result would be to replace the previous two lines with

```
 n129 = random_perm(9)
 ix = 1
 DO jx = 1, 9
       IF (ANY(n129(1:5)==jx)) THEN
          lotto5(ix) = jx
          ix = ix+1
       END IF
 END DO
```

From a limited amount of testing:

- I'm reasonably confident this works correctly.
- It's slower than OP's code by about 2-4%.

If OP's only concern is speed OP might care to 'inline' the function manually to see if it makes a jot of difference.  I haven't done that, and wouldn't. I think it's useful to have a random permutation generator in a stand-alone function.  OP hints that this function (or rather OP's representation of it in the code posted) is part of a much larger code, so whether the function I've provided is useful in that context I don't know.

Finally, to address OP's wider question, is what I have written any better than the original ?

No, it's slower.

Arguably, yes.  If OP's intention is to take the first `m` elements of a random permutation of the integers `1,2,...,n` then a function to return a random permutation is a useful component for larger programs.  But OP might legitimately argue that his (?) code is a better (because faster) implementation of that function but just wrapped up differently.

Which takes us back to the beginning, whaddya mean by *better* ?